# I still have the Ubuntu 11.10 screen while booting

Tags: 12.04, boot

I have upgraded to 12.04 but when I boot the PC I still get the purple 11.10 screen with the white dots.

How do I change this?

I am running on an AMD64 processor and have an Nvidia GE 9300 graphics card

Answer (score 0):

Both 11.10 and 12.04 comes with LightDM.

Purple screen and white dots you are referencing to is actually LightDM welcome screen. It hasn't visually changed between 11.10 and 12.04.

**11.10** LightDM welcome screen:

[image]

**12.04** LightDM welcome screen:

[image]